# collapsing date records if the value does not change

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to work this solution on how to collapse the records based on a value..

Table 1(Input)

```
 Emp_ID Start_Date  End_Date    Rating  Department  Salary
2000    01012011    12312011    A   HR          10000
2000    01012012    12319999    A   HR          20000
3000    01012011    12312011    B   Operations  50000
3000    01012012    12312012    B   Operations  60000
3000    01012013    12319999    C   Operations  70000
```

Table 2(Output)

```
 Emp_ID Start_Date  End_Date    Rating  Department
2000    01012011    12319999    A   HR
3000    01012011    12312012    B   Operations
3000    01012013    12319999    C   Operations
```

Database is oracle. I just need some start on how to solve this problem so that i can work on it..

Thanks in Advance..

**EDIT:** Assuming that Table 1 & Table 2 has EMP_NAME column. But i am not able to load this column in table2 as group by wont let me do that..(I am talking abt the soln given by Pablo Santa Cruz)

Any solutions on this..

**EDIT:**  Edited the table structure agan..sorry for confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select emp_id, rating, min(start_date), max(end_date)
  from table_1
 group by emp_id, rating
```

If you need to actually store the values on `table_2` table, start the previous SQL statement with `create table table_2 as`.

Considering what you've comment, you can do:

```
create table table_2 as
select emp_id, rating, min(start_date), max(end_date), 
       'EMP_DEPT_INFO' as emp_deparment
  from table_1
 group by emp_id, rating
```

Other possibility might be creating the table first, and then doing an `alter table` to include the new column.

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution..you saved me. Yes, I need to load this data to another table 2 but i need to add one more column but group by won't let me add that column in the select section..Can u suggest a way out?

Comment: @javanoob: what do you need to be stored on that extra column?

Comment: What if the values go up and back down?  This only works (using min/max) if the employee *never* returns to an old salary rating.